# How can I launch the certificate manager (from Internet options) from the command line?

Tags: windows-xp, cmd.exe

By `inetcpl.cpl` using on the command line, it triggers the Internet options window.

Are there any advanced options of `inetcpl.cpl` available  from the command line?

1. **Tab selection**, i.e Content tab.
2. **Launch new window from Internet option**, i.e Certificate windows.

Is it feasible or what is the right direction?

Information: I would like to run a .bat file to open the Internet Options' `Certificate Window`.

Comment: Would the Certificate Manager via the Management Console (`certmgr.msc`) be acceptable? It should display the same certificates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To select a specific tab, pass that tab as the final number in the following command:

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL inetcpl.cpl,,3
```

The 3 will give you the content tab under at least Windows XP. I am unsure about other versions.

To get directly to the certificate UI (bypasses inetcpl.cpl entirely),

```
rundll32.exe cryptui.dll,CryptUIStartCertMgr
```

For completeness, here are the functions that cryptui.dll exposes; however, they are ~~almost entirely undocumented.~~ I found the documentation on them by *[searching for "CryptUi"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/windows?query=CryptUi&Refinement=183&emptyWatermark=true&searchButtonTooltip=Search&ac=2)*

It looks like if you're going to want to highlight a specific certificate you're going to need to use at least PowerShell, rather than batch, and it's going to be a little bit hairy.

```
ACUIProviderInvokeUI
CryptUIDlgCertMgr
CryptUIDlgFreeCAContext
CryptUIDlgSelectCA
CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateA
CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore
CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateW
CryptUIDlgSelectStoreA
CryptUIDlgSelectStoreW
CryptUIDlgViewCRLA
CryptUIDlgViewCRLW
CryptUIDlgViewCTLA
CryptUIDlgViewCTLW
CryptUIDlgViewCertificateA
CryptUIDlgViewCertificatePropertiesA
CryptUIDlgViewCertificatePropertiesW
CryptUIDlgViewCertificateW
CryptUIDlgViewContext
CryptUIDlgViewSignerInfoA
CryptUIDlgViewSignerInfoW
CryptUIFreeCertificatePropertiesPagesA
CryptUIFreeCertificatePropertiesPagesW
CryptUIFreeViewSignaturesPagesA
CryptUIFreeViewSignaturesPagesW
CryptUIGetCertificatePropertiesPagesA
CryptUIGetCertificatePropertiesPagesW
CryptUIGetViewSignaturesPagesA
CryptUIGetViewSignaturesPagesW
CryptUIStartCertMgr
CryptUIWizBuildCTL
CryptUIWizCertRequest
CryptUIWizCreateCertRequestNoDS
CryptUIWizDigitalSign
CryptUIWizExport
CryptUIWizFreeCertRequestNoDS
CryptUIWizFreeDigitalSignContext
CryptUIWizImport
CryptUIWizQueryCertRequestNoDS
CryptUIWizSubmitCertRequestNoDS
DllRegisterServer
DllUnregisterServer
EnrollmentCOMObjectFactory_getInstance
I_CryptUIProtect
I_CryptUIProtectFailure
LocalEnroll
LocalEnrollNoDS
RetrievePKCS7FromCA
WizardFree
```

Comment: Perfect :) Tested and works fine on Windows-XP, how about opening the Content Tab's property? i.e Certificate

Comment: Working on it, it's probably some CLSID somewhere, I just have to hunt it down.

Comment: Found it, editing post.

Comment: It works like charm, thank you so much! :) Okay, I wonder if this works, How about navigating to 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities' tab and locate/highlight a particular certificate, with name is given?

Comment: @Roylee, I'm sorry, I can't find any documentation on the functions within cryptui.dll, I used dependency walker to grab a list, and I've added that to my answer, but Microsoft doesn't reveal what these functions do, and what parameters they expect.

Comment: I stand corrected, and I've edited my post once again.

Comment: No problem :) Thanks for helping me so far, deeply appreciate for the effort! :) Is `CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore` working on my case? Even navigation to 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities' store is good enough for me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11427/discussion-between-omnipotententity-and-roylee)